# Website fatal error 9001

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I know this question has been asked here before, but none of the suggestions have worked for me.

I have an ASP.NET MVC (v. 3) website on a shared server. The website was working fine for a few weeks now, until I started getting a `Fatal Error 9001` error straight after login.

Because this is a shared server, there are only very limited things I can do with the database (and I don't know that much about databases anyway). The help desk insist that there is nothing wrong with their server. I got various suggestions from them:

- Upgrading to the business plan because I am out of space
- Even though the mdb file is small, the ldb can grow very quickly. The ldb file is probably taking up all the space. I have 100MB available, the database size is 16.5MB. Can the ldb file take up the remaining space?
- There is something wrong with my SQL queries and I should check the website. I'm using EF with linq to sql. Everything was working fine until now... Can there be something that goes wrong in the queries that causes this sort of error?
- There is nothing wrong to be seen in the db logs, so this error cannot possibly have happened. I should log it next time it happens and contact again.

I found some posts on SO suggesting that restoring a DB backup can get rid of the issue. I do not have a recent backup, and can't take a new one because of a `fatal error 9001` occurring.

What else can I do/try to get my website moving again?

UPDATE:

I heard back from the helpdesk hosting the site today. They tell me that the following error message.

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/23/2012 6:50:03 AM 
Event time (UTC): 11/23/2012 12:50:03 PM 
Event ID: 55fd03ff030d4d05bf791aa57b726df4 
Event sequence: 8 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/9891/ROOT-1-129981485984030000 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\ClientSites\friedemannallgayer.com\httpdocs\ 
    Machine name: ASPHOST94 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 87868 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: ASPHOST94\IWPD_293(friedemann) 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: Warning: Fatal error 9001 occurred at Nov 23 2012  6:50AM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at PapaFilmsDB.Models.AccountMembershipService.ValidateUser(String userName, String password) in C:\Users\david.DOMAIN_GIS\Dropbox\Programming\PapaFilmsDB\PapaFilmsDB_20121029\PapaFilmsDB\Data\Models\AccountModels.cs:line 119
   at PapaFilmsDB.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in C:\Users\david.DOMAIN_GIS\Dropbox\Programming\PapaFilmsDB\PapaFilmsDB_20121029\PapaFilmsDB\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.friedemannallgayer.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/ 
    Request path: /Account/LogOn 
    User host address: 93.219.156.103 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: ASPHOST94\IWPD_293(friedemann) 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 9 
    Thread account name: ASPHOST94\IWPD_293(friedemann) 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at PapaFilmsDB.Models.AccountMembershipService.ValidateUser(String userName, String password) in C:\Users\david.DOMAIN_GIS\Dropbox\Programming\PapaFilmsDB\PapaFilmsDB_20121029\PapaFilmsDB\Data\Models\AccountModels.cs:line 119
   at PapaFilmsDB.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(LogOnModel model, String returnUrl) in C:\Users\david.DOMAIN_GIS\Dropbox\Programming\PapaFilmsDB\PapaFilmsDB_20121029\PapaFilmsDB\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 40
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Can anybody make sense of this with regards to the 9001 error? They claim that it is a problem with my site or with `.net 4.0`. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, the log (LDB) can grow to be larger than the actual data. The obvious question is, are you out of database space? I assume you and/or the helpdesk can see that.

Comment: Yes they can. After I pushed them a bit they admitted that the total db size is 25MB. The available space is 100MB, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You may check this out](https://serverfault.com/questions/238394/diagnosing-microsoft-sql-server-error-9001-the-log-for-the-database-is-not-avai)

Since you use a shared server, the occurrence for database corruption is high and you have little authority for server configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I already saw that post, but couldn't find anything helpful in there as I can't actually execute anything against the server. I think I will try pointing that post out to the helpdesk, see if that gets them moving.

Comment: I think that's what it was. The problem ended up resolving itself over the next week-end after it first occurred. On querying, the helpdesk said that the website and the DB may be restarted during periodically (logically the week-end is a good candidate for automated admin tasks). Restarting the DB probably did the trick in this case.

Answer (score 8):

I got this today and "fixed" it by taking the database offline and then bringing it online again. It's just treating the symptoms not the cause so the problem might jump up again, but at least by database can do write actions again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error occur without my knowledge on one database that wasn't used. It later escalated over a few days to two databases and today it occurred on all. I fixed the symptom by **restarting the windows service instance** but still have no idea why on earth it happened in the first place!